# If $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $u=f(r)$ then prove $ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} =f''(r)+\frac{1}{r}f'(r)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

We have $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $u=f(r)$ then prove , from chain rule I know that 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}.\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}.\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}$$
Hence , $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{r}$$ similarly
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{r}$$
therefore $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f'(r).\frac{x}{r} $$
and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=f'(r).\frac{y}{r} $$
finally 
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=f''(x).\frac{x}{r}+f'(r).\frac{r^2-x^2}{r^3}$$
finally 
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=f''(x).\frac{y}{r}+f'(r).\frac{r^2-y^2}{r^3}$$
Now summation of both double partial derivative clearly is't equal to one given in question , where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making an error in taking the second derivative.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(f'(r) \frac{x}{r}\right) &= \frac{x}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f'(r) + f'(r)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x}{r} \\
&= \frac{x}{r}\left( f''(r) \frac{x}{r}\right) + f'(r) \left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{x}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}r \right) \\
&= f''(r)\frac{x^2}{r^2} + f'(r)\left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{x^2}{r^3}\right)
\end{align}

doing the same thing for $y$, we'll end up with 
\begin{align}
u_{xx} + u_{yy} &= f''(r)\left(\frac{x^2+ y^2}{r^2} \right) + f'(r)\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{r^3}\right) \\
&= f''(r) + \frac{f'(r)}{r}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain me how partial derivative of f'(r) becomes f''(r).x/r instead of just f''(r)

Comment: The same way the partial of $f$ is $f'(r) \frac{x}{r}$. $f'$ is just another function, $g$, and it's partial must have the same form.

Comment: This is, of course, a consequence of the chain rule. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(r) = \frac{\partial  g(r)}{\partial r}  \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$$.